# Unable to override RSpec Sysntax module method

Tags: ruby, rspec, overriding

I wanted to override the expect in under Syntax module. So, i have placed the below code into the .config/initializers/syntax.rb file

```
 module RSpec
  module Expectations
    module Syntax
      def enable_expect(syntax_host=::RSpec::Matchers)
        return if expect_enabled?(syntax_host)

        syntax_host.module_exec do
          def expect(value=::RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget::UndefinedValue, &block)
            ::RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget.for(value, block)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And required this inside the env.rb file.

```
require_relative '../../.config/initializers/syntax'
```

This is not overriding the existing method. I'm using RSpec gem 3.2.0

What went wrong with the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to put this override codes in **spec/support** directory and require it in **rails or spec helper** instead of putting in initializers.